# Como poner el mismo numero en varios metodos

Tags: java, jbutton

estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual tengo 2 switchs uno de enunciados y otro para comprobar los botones si estan correctamente, entonces mi duda es si hay alguna manera de poder hacer que vayan a la par el numero "indice".

Tengo 2 botones con 1 metodo cada uno y en cada boton llama a su metodo, como se puede observar a continuacion:

```
// Genera un Enunciado
private void GenerarbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        EnunciadoAleat(num);
    }                                          

//Comprueba el enunciado generado
    private void ComprobarBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        ComprobarResult(num);

    }                                            

    private void EnunciadoAleat(int num) {

        switch (num) {
            case 1:
                enunciadoJlbl.setText("Zuma y Chase 1");

                break;
            case 2:
                enunciadoJlbl.setText("Marshall y Rubble 2");
                break;
            case 3:
                enunciadoJlbl.setText("Rubble y Everest 3");
                break;
           }

    }

    private void ComprobarResult(int num) {

        switch (num) {
            case 1:
                if ((ZumaBox.isSelected() && ChaseBox.isSelected()) && (SkyBox.isSelected() || RockyBox.isSelected() || EverestBox.isSelected() || RubbleBox.isSelected() || MarshallBox.isSelected())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intentalo de nuevo", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                } else if (ZumaBox.isSelected() && ChaseBox.isSelected()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enhorabuena lo has conseguido", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Intentalo de nuevo", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                enunciadoJlbl.setText("2");
                break;
            case 3:
                enunciadoJlbl.setText("3");
                break;
          }

    }
```

[image: Imagen Interfaz]

Lo que quiero es que cuando pulse generar un contador sea 1, y cuando le de a Comprobar ese contador lo pueda usar tambien en el matodo comprobar y entonces cuando le vuelva a dar a generar que el contador pase a ser 2 y en comprobar igual.

Comment: ¿Qué significa "vayan a la vez"? ¿Te refieres a que pulses el botón que pulses, se llame a la función correspondiente con el mismo num? ¿Quién posiciona num antes de que pulses el botón? Vas a tener que explicarte un poco mejor porque no termino de entender lo que necesitas

Comment: En plan tengo un jLabel y esta vacio entonces cuando pulso generar enunciado, me sale el enunciado de num que por ejemplo es 1 y a la hora de comprobar quiero que la funcion de comprobar tenga el mimos numero que el de generar.

Comment: Hola @SuperG280, trate de subir una imagen para que tengamos una mejor perspectiva de su problema.

Comment: Intentaste colocar la variable `num` de manera global?.

Comment: Si, en plan contador pero no se como hacerlo para que vaya aumentando cada vez que pulse el boton

Comment: Pues sí, como te ha recomendado @MoisésHuamánC. si defines num como global o miembro de la clase donde tienes todas estas funciones, seteas el valor de num al valor que quieras y mientras no le cambies el valor, siempre tendrá el mismo. Lo siento pero me resulta tan obvio que asumo que no he entendido lo que te pasa.

Comment: Dentro del método solo escribe `num++;` Lo que hace es sumar 1 cada vez que se ejecuta, lo lo mismo que hacer `num = num + 1`, pero de forma abreviada.

Comment: Haciendolo como tu dices al ser global, genera el enunciado 1 y comprueba el del 2 luego genera el enunciado 3 y me comprueba el del 4

Comment: @SuperG280 lo que quiero es que cada vez que pulso el boton de generar me cambie el numero y eso es lo que no se hacer para que luego con el parametro que le paso al metodo del numero me pueda comprobar si esta bien seleccionado.

Comment: Si siempre tienes que pulsar los botones en ese orden, primero generas y luego compruebas, incrementa num solo en el segundo botón. Posicionas a 1, pulsas el primero y genera el 1, luego pulsas comprobar y comprueba el 1 y antes de terminar, incrementas. La siguiente vez que generes ya tendrá valor 2. El problema de esto es qué pasa si el usuario no pulsa los botones en el orden. Para resolver esto, puedes inhabilitar el según botón y habilitarlo solo cuando ha pulsado el primero. Y al pulsar el segundo lo vuelves a deshabilitar.

Comment: Muchas gracias @SuperG280 voy a intentar hacer algo asi.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que necesitas que la variable `num` esté de forma global para que dentro de sus funciones pueda usar la misma variable.

Básicamente sería:

```
int num = 0; // Inicializamos la variable en 0

private void EnunciadoAleat(int num) {

num++; // Agregamos el contador

switch (num) {
    case 1:
      enunciadoJlbl.setText("Zuma y Chase 1");
      break;
    case 2:
      enunciadoJlbl.setText("Marshall y Rubble 2");
      break;
    case 3:
      enunciadoJlbl.setText("Rubble y Everest 3");
      break;
  }

}
```

En tu otro método no es necesario, si lo haces, el contador sumará una vez más y no comprobarás el valor que generaste, sino que comprobarás el siguiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @MoisésHuamánC.

Comment: De nada @Anonimo. Saludos :D.